# CRRA utility application

Tags: programming, risk

I fitted a CRRA utility function to daily S&P 500 returns in R. (As for instance in [Optimal Option Portfolio Strategies](http://www.efmaefm.org/0EFMAMEETINGS/EFMA%20ANNUAL%20MEETINGS/2011-Braga/papers/0344.pdf), page 10)

```
expostutility = function(x,y) { mean( (1/(1-y)) * ((1+x)^(1-y)) ) }
test = na.omit(diff(log(getSymbols('SPY', from='2010-01-01', auto.assign = F)[,4])))
expostutility(test, 5); expostutility(test, 20)
```

For 5: -0.249841 For 20: -0.05321077
Why is the stock market utility higher for higher risk aversion? (Using (correctly) simple returns instead of log does not change the fact.)

EDIT:

```
test1=rnorm(1000, mean=0.01, sd=0.01)
test2=rnorm(1000, mean=0.01, sd=0.05)
expostutility(test1, 2)
expostutility(test2, 2)
expostutility(test1, 10)
expostutility(test2, 10)
```

Here the second series has less utility than the first; the ordering is always correct. But there is much higher overall utility with *higher* gamma (i.e., risk aversion). (?) Maybe EU can not be interpreted as such as has to be converted to certainty equivalents?

Comment: Usually one works with the utility of end of period wealth (i.e. $W_{t+1}$), not of returns. See section 2.3 on Page 9. Basically I would work with with $1+r$, not with $r$.

Comment: It is just as incorrect to call a CRRA function with a negative value as it is to call a sqrt function with a negative value. If stocks go up 5 percent the utility is $U(1.05)$, of they go down 5 percent the utility is $U(0.95)$

Comment: Hi Alex! Yes, it's 1+r in the formula. I have seen exactly this formula in another paper called Do constraints improve portfolio performance?

Comment: You are using test1=rnorm(1000, mean=0.01, sd=0.01). That's wrong. It should be test1=1.0+rnorm(1000, mean=0.01, sd=0.01).

Comment: I substituted W by 1+r in the function, see: ((1+x)^(1-y))